# Simple Client Server Java Program not going into while loop

Tags: java, server, client

I had stumbled upon a dead block when doing my assignment. It's a simple server and client program.
The details of this program is as follows;

1. Create a server class `EncryptServer` that listens for incoming connections. If there is a connection, accept it and create a thread `EncryptServerSession` to handle the input and output stream.
2. Create a thread class `EncryptServerSession` that takes in the input and output stream from the server class and process it.
3. Create a client class `EncryptClient` that connects to the server class and takes output stream from `EncryptServerSession` through `EncryptServer`.

Somehow the while true loop of the `EncryptClient` class is not working. I cannot seem to get into the loop. Is something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

**EncryptServer**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptServer
{    
    public EncryptServer() throws IOException
    {
         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1122);
         System.out.println("Server started."); 
     
         while (true)
         {
             Socket conSocket = serverSocket.accept();
             System.out.println("Client connected from " + 
conSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostName()); 
         
             Thread session = new 
EncryptServerSession(conSocket.getInputStream(), 
conSocket.getOutputStream());
             session.start();
         }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            EncryptServer server = new EncryptServer();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }                                      
    }      
}
```

**EncryptServerSession**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptServerSession extends Thread
{
    BufferedReader in;
    Writer out;

    public EncryptServerSession(InputStream inStream, OutputStream outStream)
    {
        Reader read = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
        in = new BufferedReader(read);
        out = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);
    }
    
    public void strEncrypt()
    {
        try
        {
            String message = in.readLine();
            out.write(message);
            out.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //System.out.println(in.readLine());
            out.write("Please enter the message to be encrypted: ");
            out.flush();
            
            //strEncrypt();
        
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

**EncryptClient**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptClient
{
    BufferedReader input, userTerm;
    Writer output;
    String line;
    
    public EncryptClient() throws IOException
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 1122);
        Reader read = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        input = new BufferedReader(read);
        
        userTerm = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        output = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());             
        
        /////////////// Somehow I cannot get into this loop, why? //////////
        while (true) 
        {
            System.out.println("test ");
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
            System.out.println("Enter message to be encrypted: ");
            output.write(userTerm.readLine());        
            output.flush();
        }
        /////////////// Somehow I cannot get into this loop, why? //////////
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
          EncryptClient client = new EncryptClient();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please go through your EncryptClient constructor and add System.out.pritnln("test"); or something like that on every line (one by one)? It would be helpful to know exactly which line of your code it is getting hung up on.

Comment: Did you run main method of EncryptServer prior to running main method of EncryptClient? If not, it may be the case, because you should run your server first and then client. By the way, what do you have as an ouput in your console after execution?

Comment: I once had an issue on my school network where the localhost didn't translate to 127.0.0.1. You could try hardcoding in 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. I'm not a professional at networks but worth a shot. Also make sure to start your server before your client, since the most likely culprit for error is the socket and streams before your loop.

Comment: Hi, I did run the server first and then the client. Everything is working, the server is able to connect to the server. It's just that I cannot get into the loop for encryptclient. That's the place where the code has hung

Comment: When using text protocols, always make sure to use println() or to always print an explicit "\n".

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to send a message to a server, do some logic, then send it back to the client. The above code seems to run well on my side. Here's what I've done:

- run `EncryptServer` first. I expect this is the issue you are facing. or maybe your firewall isn't letting you listen on sockets.
- in `EncryptServerSession`, You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. either `close` the stream or write a new line after you finish.

  ```
  ...

  out.write(message);
  out.write("\r\n"); // write new line
  out.flush();

  ...

  } finally {
      try {
        out.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
      }
  }
  ```

  OR

  ```
  ...

  out.write(message);
  out.write("\r\n"); // write new line
  out.flush();

  ...
  ```

Comment: Hi yes, it's running well for me too. The server and client are working. I just cannot get into the loop for encrypt client, not sure why.